# How to get public name tag by Etherscan api?

Tags: etherscan

Does anyone know how to use Etherscan API to get public name tag of a contract?

For example for this contract https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7 I would like to get "Tether: USDT Stablecoin"

Comment: I think you need to manually contact them for that via email. That's also how you get them to add your token's icon.

Comment: There is an [npm module](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102156/how-to-get-public-name-tag-by-etherscan-api) that will scrape this information for you.